# Spotify Request for an End Point Reference based on MAC address

Tags: spotify

Is there any reference for requesting a userid or a playlist for a user based on a MAC address of the user phone?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

No, we don't persist MAC addresses in any way, so there's no way to make requests based on them.